# Circular Model & Iterative Calculation in R

Tags: r

I have an Excel model that I would like to replicate with R. The Excel model contains numerous circular references which require Excel's iterative calculations to be turned on to function properly.

Below I am attaching two images of a very simplified spreadsheet. The first image contains the values and the second contains the formulas.

Essentially what this toy model is meant to represent is a company that has three separate entities, each of which have a certain amount of value, along with three lenders that have liens on the collateral of the entities. "Recipient 1" has first liens on all three entities (color coded in yellow), "Recipient 2" has a second lien only on "Entity 1" and "Recipient 3" has a second lien only on "Entity 2." Recipient 1 will recover its value from the three entities on a pro-rata basis.

All of the above is rather straight forward. Where it gets circular is to the extent that an Entity has "Excess Value," that value would flow back to another entity, which increases the value of whichever entities receives that value. This circular aspect is what I'm not sure how to solve with R.

(Note: the real model contains an even greater degree of circularity, as "Excess Value" may flow through one entity, into another, into another, etc. so ideally a solution would be able to handle such real world complexity)

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

**Values**
[image]

**Formulas**
[image]

Comment: You could look at iteration as time steps, assuming 'performance' (everyone's following the contracts; no entity is funding another until it receives funds due), there are only so many 'steps' to execute.

Comment: Apologies, I don't follow. Could you explain how you would specifically implement with this example, and then we could discuss whether the solution scales?

Comment: Convert the problem to the  form `x <- f(x)` for some function `f` then `x <- init.value; for(i in 1:n) x <- f(x)` where you need to define `init.value`, `n` and `f` appropriately.

Comment: In your answer, should I assume that "n" should be arbitrarily set to the equivalent of Excel's "maximum iterations" (say, 100) since the true value n is unknowable.

Comment: Not unknowable, but typically guessed at. I was imagining this as a `while` rather than `for` , based on final values being known/knowable.